# JS: Generating a zip file with "store" level compression

Tags: javascript, zip, compression

I want to make a zip file in JavaScript with "store" level compression, i.e. no compression, without having to download a whole library like JSzip because most of the functionality isn't needed. Is there a good way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zip file format is relatively straightforward. You can implement your own zip file creation routines that only produce stored entries. You can find the [zip file format documented here](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is generate the zip file on the server and let users download it.